# Put an animate wind vector field on a georeferenced pictured

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I need an advice about a project. I would like to put a wind vector field on a picture. This picture is a static map of concentration of pollutants. 
I don't need interactive map like this : https://www.ventusky.com/ but just like a gif I mean. My question is : Is it correct if I used Leaflet librairies like L.canvasLayer.vectorFieldAnim ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Image overlay, you can find how to use it in leafletjs.com